# Delete tasks in Google Earth Engine using CLI?

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-1

I am trying to clear/delete my google earth engine tasks window with several commands but they do not work:

```
`earthengine task cancel all`
`earthengine task cancel TASK_ID`
`tasks.clear()`


tasks.clear()
```

```
// Load the Sentinel-1 ImageCollection.
var imgVV = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
        .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VV'))
        .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'IW'));


var desc = imgVV.filter(ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass', 'DESCENDING'));
var asc = imgVV.filter(ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass', 'ASCENDING'));

var date = ee.Filter.date('2015-03-01', '2015-04-20');
// Filter by date and geometry, create multiband image and clip to geometry
// var ascChange = ee.ImageCollection(asc.filterDate('2015-03-01', '2015-06-20')).filterBounds(geometry).toBands().toFloat().clip(geometry)
// var ascChange = ee.ImageCollection(asc.filterDate('2015-03-01', '2015-06-20')).filterBounds(geometry)


var ascChange = asc.filter(date).filterBounds(geometry)
print(ascChange)


Map.addLayer(ascChange, {min: -25, max: 5}, 'Multi-T Mean ASC', true);

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: ascChange,
  description:'Ascendente_CMillor_lunes',
  fileNamePrefix: 'scenedate_orbitProperties_pass_GRD',
  scale: 10,
  region: geometry})
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites. We're a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the command line tool, paste the task ID without quotes:

```
earthengine task cancel VY62ZYT6YV27DAVVKS3JYV42
```

Comment: Tasks list are completed or failed, It does not work.

Comment: Of course, if they're completed or failed, there's nothing to cancel in the first place. The task list shows a complete overview of **all** tasks (limited to the last 300 I believe) that were started, including failed, completed, running, queued and cancelled tasks. Only running and queued tasks can be cancelled.